# Boost serialization throws "input stream error" after a certain file size

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I am using Boost::serialization to read/write to a file which contains 3d models.

After a certain size of the file (around 8-12kb+), serialization throws an "Input Stream Error" exception every time I try to read the file. It works fine every single time untill then - for example I can read/write a 1kb model 12 times successfully, then on the 13th time and onwards it will throw exception!

Here's the code to serialize/deserialize:

```
    JonsPackagePtr ReadJonsPkg(const std::string& jonsPkgName)
    {
        std::ifstream jonsPkgStream(jonsPkgName.c_str(), std::fstream::binary || std::fstream::in);
        JonsPackagePtr pkg(new JonsPackage());   // "JonsPackagePtr" is a boost_shared_ptr typedef

        if (jonsPkgStream && jonsPkgStream.good() && jonsPkgStream.is_open())
        {
            boost::archive::binary_iarchive iar(jonsPkgStream);

            iar >> (*pkg.get());
        }

        return pkg;
    }

    bool WriteJonsPkg(const std::string& jonsPkgName, const JonsPackagePtr pkg)
    {
        std::ofstream outStream(jonsPkgName.c_str(), std::fstream::out | std::fstream::binary);
        bool ret = false;

        if (outStream.is_open())
        {
            boost::archive::binary_oarchive oar(outStream);
            oar << (*pkg.get());

            ret = true;
        }

        return ret;
    }
```

Here's the contents that I archive:

```
/* PackageHeader definition */
    struct PackageHeader
    {
        std::string mSignature;
        uint8_t mMajorVersion;
        uint8_t mMinorVersion;


        PackageHeader();
    };

    /* PackageMesh definition */
    struct PackageMesh
    {
        std::vector<float> mVertexData;
        std::vector<uint32_t> mIndiceData;


        PackageMesh();
    };

    /* PackageModel definition */
    struct PackageModel
    {
        std::string mName;
        std::vector<PackageModel> mChildren;
        std::vector<PackageMesh> mMeshes;
        Mat4 mTransform;


        PackageModel();
    };

    /* JonsPackage definition */
    struct JonsPackage
    {
        PackageHeader mHeader;
        std::vector<PackageModel> mModels;


        JonsPackage();
    };


    typedef boost::shared_ptr<JonsPackage> JonsPackagePtr;
    JonsPackagePtr ReadJonsPkg(const std::string& jonsPkgName);
    bool WriteJonsPkg(const std::string& jonsPkgName, const JonsPackagePtr pkg);


    /* PackageHeader inlines */
    inline PackageHeader::PackageHeader() : mSignature("jons"), mMajorVersion(LatestMajorVersion), mMinorVersion(LatestMinorVersion)
    {
    }

    /* PackageModel inlines */
    inline PackageModel::PackageModel() : mName(""), mTransform(1.0f)
    {
    }

    /* PackageMesh inlines */
    inline PackageMesh::PackageMesh()
    {
    }

    /* JonsPackage inlines */
    inline JonsPackage::JonsPackage()
    {
    }
```

Finally here's my non-intrusive serialization definitions:

```
namespace boost
{
    namespace serialization
    {
        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, JonsEngine::PackageHeader& header, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & header.mMajorVersion;
            ar & header.mMinorVersion;
            ar & header.mSignature;
        }

        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, JonsEngine::PackageModel& model, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & model.mName;
            ar & model.mChildren;
            ar & model.mMeshes;
            ar & model.mTransform;
        }

        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, JonsEngine::PackageMesh& mesh, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & mesh.mVertexData;
            ar & mesh.mIndiceData;
        }

        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, JonsEngine::JonsPackage& pkg, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & pkg.mHeader;
            ar & pkg.mModels;
        }

        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, glm::detail::tmat4x4<glm::mediump_float> transform, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & transform[0];
            ar & transform[1];
            ar & transform[2];
            ar & transform[3];
        }

        template<class Archive>
        void serialize(Archive & ar, glm::detail::tvec4<glm::mediump_float> vec, const unsigned int version)
        {
            ar & vec.x;
            ar & vec.y;
            ar & vec.z;
            ar & vec.w;
        }
    } // namespace serialization
} // namespace boost
```

As I mentioned above, **it is only after a certain file size (8-12kb+) that it starts throwing the exceptions when I try to read it.** Why on earth is this and what could possibly cause it? It goes fine up untill this point...

Thanks

Comment: that is probable not the issue here but in `ReadJonsPkg` you should use bitwise or: `std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::in`

Comment: Not, that WAS the issue. You sir, wins the interwebz. Make an answer and I'll gladly tag and upvote it

Comment: ... and I was just starting to dig deeper :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in `ReadJonsPkg` you should use bitwise or: `std::fstream::binary | std::fstream::in`